# Triggering a long operation using camel rest service

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, jbossfuse

I want to trigger a long operation using camel rest call. Since, the operation takes significant amount of time, the request will get timeout and show an error message on client side. I don't want this to happen.

So, I am trying to solve this problem using a queue as follows:

```
<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
   <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616" />
   <property name="userName" value="admin"/>
   <property name="password" value="admin"/>
</bean>

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint" trace="true">
    <route>
        <from uri="cxfrs:bean:rsprovider" />
        <setBody>
             <simple>${header.operationName}</simple>
        </setBody>
        <to uri="activemq:queue:myqueue"/>
        <!-- Send immediate response to client as, the processing will take a while -->
        <setBody>
            <simple>Received feeder service request to ${header.operationName}. Request will be processed soon.</simple>
        </setBody>
    </route>

    <route>
      <from uri="activemq:queue:myqueue"/>
      <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
      <recipientList>
            <simple>direct-vm:operation-${body}</simple>
        </recipientList>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

But, it seems that adding to a queue is synchronous and the response is not received on time. How can I make this queue asynchronous? I tried appending `?jms.useAsyncSend=true` to the queue url. But that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should try `asyncConsumer`

```
 <from uri="activemq:queue:myqueue?asyncConsumer=true"/>
```

> Camel 2.9: Whether the JmsConsumer processes the Exchange
>   asynchronously. If enabled then the JmsConsumer may pickup the next
>   message from the JMS queue, while the previous message is being
>   processed asynchronously (by the Asynchronous Routing Engine). This
>   means that messages may be processed not 100% strictly in order. If
>   disabled (as default) then the Exchange is fully processed before the
>   JmsConsumer will pickup the next message from the JMS queue. Note: if
>   transacted has been enabled, then `asyncConsumer=true` does not run
>   asynchronously, as transactions must be executed synchronously (Camel
>   3.0 may support asynchronous transactions).

Also check the Async Request Reply APIs

http://camel.apache.org/async.html

```
Future<Object> future = template.asyncRequestBody("activemq:queue:myqueue", "<YOUR_MESSAGE>");
```